how do split or separate character strings in rows of a column
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Nigerian_House_of_Representatives_election'

html_content = read_html(url)

tables = html_table(html_content, fill = TRUE)

tb_abia = tables[[9]]

#remove first row
names(tb_abia) <- tb_abia[1,]
tb_abia <- tb_abia[-1,] 
view(tb_abia)

tb_abia$Status
[1] "Incumbent renominatedNew member electedLP gain"                                                                         
[2] "Incumbent retiredNew member electedLP gain"  

the above column (tb_abia$Status) is what i want to split into: "Incumbent renominated", "New member elected", "LP gain","incumbent retired" etc

Without an example of your data and the desired output it's difficult to provide a detailed answer. Please have a look at how to provide the necessary information here

library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Nigerian_House_of_Representatives_election'
html_content = read_html(url)
tables = html_table(html_content, fill = TRUE)
class(tables)
tb_abia = tables[[9]]
class(tb_abia)
view(tb_abia)
#remove first row
names(tb_abia) <- tb_abia[1,]
tb_abia <- tb_abia[-1,]
view(tb_abia)
tb_abia$Status


tb_abia$Status #column i want to split its values into separate columns
[1] "Incumbent renominatedNew member electedLP gain"
[2] "Incumbent retiredNew member electedLP gain"
[3] "Incumbent re-elected"


In this case using xml_find_all(html_content, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", "\n") and then xml_find_all(html_content, ".//br") %>% xml_remove() before calling html_table will result in "Incumbent renominated\nNew member elected\nLP gain" which you can then split on \n.

@Marijn am grateful but struggling on how to split on \n gave me a weird outcome

Can you specify, what about the outcome is 'weird'? One way to do the splitting would be tb_abia$Status <- str_split(tb_abia$Status,"\n"), then the first row would be tb_abia$Status[[1]] and the elements are tb_abia$Status[[1]][1] (Incumbent renominated), tb_abia$Status[[1]][2] (New member elected) and tb_abia$Status[[1]][3] (LP gain).

The comment from Marijn is a nice solution for your problem.
Here's another "quick and dirty" suggestion:
tb_abia |> 
mutate(Status=gsub("(New member elected)", '_\\1_',Status)) |>
separate(Status, into=c("S1","S2","S3"),sep="_")

Note that you might want to add more split cases, so, feel free to modify the code provided.

interestingly, what you see as "quick and dirty" suggestion, seems to be giving me a headway, wish i can screenshot the result for you to see

@BashirAbubakar I am glad I could help! no need for the screenshot, I saw the result

thanks i deeply appreciate, one last thing please: how do i make those rows showing NA i.e. in which the incumbent won reelection in this case S2 to be for instance 'won reelection' and S3 to be the incumbent party's gain i.e. 'PDP hold' so that it counts for the party

@BashirAbubakar add another mutate at the end: mutate(S2=ifelse(is.na(S2),'won reelection',S2), S3=ifelse(is.na(S3),"PDP hold",S3))

Words cannot express my gratitude for this, once again thanks a million

sorry forgot add this, in columns such as S1 where i have rows containing: 'Incumbent withdrew from primary[g][39]Incumbent lost re-election under nomination of new party', please how do i keep only the part 'Incumbent lost re-election under nomination of new party' as well as remove numbers and brackets from the rows. thanks
